# Understanding iPhone App Background States

Tags: iphone, xcode, background, states

I've got a tricky question. In my app user can change if he want app to run in background or not. If yes - it should work until user kills it. If not - it should work until user presses home button, and SHOULD work after locking screen with top button.

So, there is a line in plist file called "application does not run in background". If i make it "YES" - app running until home button pressed, and still working after locking screen. Perfect. If i make it "NO" - app running all the time until i kill it. Perfect.

But i guess you can't change plist value from app. Well i've found a way to do that with applicationDidEnterBackground:

```
if (userDontWantItRunInBackground) { exit(0); }
```

But there is a problem with that (except Apple don't recommend it):

```
if "application does not run in background" = YES:

applicationDidEnterBackground is NOT CALLED on locking the screen

if "application does not run in background" = NO:

applicationDidEnterBackground is CALLED on locking the screen
```

It makes no sense! This doesn't allow me to make app running on locked screen!

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 4, you can't avoid Idle time sleep if your app wish.

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

**Here is more information about background execution in iOS:**

[image]

[More:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)